# vb asp.net solution namespaces issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, methods, namespaces, solution

My solution consists of several projects.

I define my namespaces in a different folder, common to all the projects (say, some helper classes for import/export etc.).
Actually, when I use my methods from the namespaces in any project's aspx.vb file, VS shows suggestions and automatically completes them.

But the problem is that the methods (from the namespaces) are not even called, actually.

I'm writing messages to log file to see if the function is called.
It logs the messages within my aspx.vb scripts. But it refuses to log anything when methods from namespaces are called.

I definitely import all the namespaces in my aspx.vb in an appropriate way.

Anybody knows what the problem may be?

Comment: What errors do you get? It seems like there should be errors. Are you sure that your log messages just don't end up somewhere else?

Comment: @WozzeC , Absolutely sure. When the app is running there are no errors.